# Game not running in Game Maker because of the variable "font_add_sprite"?

Tags: variables, fonts, sprite, game-maker

I am using Game Maker: Studio Master Edition.
I have a problem:
Every time I run my game, a window pops up telling me:"In obj_control, in Event Draw Event number 0 at line 3: cannot use function/script name for a variable, using"font_add_sprite""
Can someone tell me what is the solution for this please? I mean is my variable wrong or what?
That is my code for Event: obj_control.Create:

```
globalvar fnt_numbers;
fnt_numbers = font_add_sprite(spr_lrg_fnt,ord("0"),true,
```

Comment: Are you using an *old* version of Game Maker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

font_add_sprite() hasn't existed for years.  See [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/214850/discussions/0/846958223182133948/?l=english) from about a year ago.  A somewhat more modern alternative is described [here](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=545165).

Comment: yeah but can you please tell me what do we use instead of font_add_sprite()

Comment: @StefanoFallaha:  Did you follow the second link?

Comment: @ErikTowers Yes i did; however, i didnt import any file that used an old GM. Actually, my GM;Studio doesn't suggest :"font_add_sprite()", but in a tutorial, the guy mentionned this variable, so can you please tell me what can I use instead of this variable?

Comment: @ErikTowers I'm sorry, I didn't follow the second link. I apoligize, thanks though